# ¿Cuál es el comando para tabular varias lineas de codigo en VS Code?

Tags: vscode

Quiero acomodar bien mi código en Visual Studio Code, le he dado formato con algunos comandos pero no encuentro uno para eliminar el espacio de la tabulación.

Ejemplo

```
                <div>
                    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="auto">
                        <tr>
                            <h1 style="margin: 0 0 10px; font-size: 40px; line-height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 20px; margin-top: 20px;">Newsletter</h1>
                            <h2 style="margin: 0 0 10px; font-size: 25px; line-height: 30px; color: #f8b214; font-weight: normal;  padding-left: 20px;">Novedades 2019</h2>
                            <hr style="width: 30%; display: inline-block; color:#ffffff;">
                            <td valign="middle" style="text-align: left; padding: 20px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #ffffff;">
                                <p style="margin: 0;">Praesent laoreet malesuada cursus. Maecenas scelerisque congue eros eu posuere. Praesent in felis ut velit pretium lobortis rhoncus ut&nbsp;erat.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

si quiero eliminar tabulación o un espacio de todas esas líneas de código al mismo tiempo, ¿qué comando es el que realiza esta función?

Comment: Puedes usar la extensión Prettier, que te puede arreglar el código de forma estándar en casi cualquier lenguaje y html.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> si quiero eliminar tabulación o un espacio de todas esas líneas de código al mismo tiempo,

En MacOs puedes usar <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>, eso regresará un margen, si lo haces varias veces eliminará la tabulación.

Si quieres darle formato al código puedes usar <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>

[image: shift plus tab]

Answer (score 6):

Para tabular varias lineas de código en `VSC` tienes que presionar <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>?</kbd> para eliminar el espacio de tabulación, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>¿</kbd> para tabular normalmente, estas dos últimas teclas están al lado del número <kbd>0</kbd>

Comment: Ya lo intenté y no funciona, creo que olvidé decir que utilizo Mac.

Comment: Prueba entonces con cmd+shift+f

Comment: Sabes como hacerlo a una sola linea?